# WGAN-GP stability loss

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, autoencoders, gan, audio

I am training a Conditional WaveGAN (1D DCGAN for audio) using WGAN-GP whose generator is of an auotencoder architecture. The network is trained to take an audio input, compress it, then decompress it into it's original waveform. I achieved reasonable accuracy after around 18 hours, but the reproduced audio quality was too low. So I left the network to keep training. However, after around 18 hours, the loss of both the critic and generator began violently oscillating at large magnitudes.

I have a couple of questions:

- What may have caused this unexpected behaviour? Did one of the adversaries learn something that the other couldn't identify, therefore causing a spiral of compounding bad gradient updates? Not enough training data (I had around 50minutes of audio broken down into 1 second chunks.)
- Prior to the spike in loss, do the critic and generator and critic loss graphs look "good"? My concern was that they both converged to 0 too quickly, before the generator was able to learn the finer, more subtle details of audio decompression. Is this a consequence of the critic being too slow to enfore such rules to the generator?

btw, I clipped the images, since some of the final datapoints reached a magnitude of ~1000. Also, the critic and generator had about 20 and 22 million parameters respectively.

[image: losses]

Answer (score 1):

I observed problems with an oscillating WGAN-GP loss, too, although my oscillation started early on during training. Therefore, the reason might be different.

However, as it may be worth a try, I resolved the problems by replacing the Gradient penalty through **Lipschitz Penalty** ([Source](https://openreview.net/forum?id=B1hYRMbCW)) as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76676534/18265340).

Basically, all that has to be done is to modify the last line of the gradient penalty computation.

TensorFlow:

```
if not liptschitz_penalty:
    # This is the standard gradient penalty
    gradient_penalty = tf.reduce_mean((slopes-1.)**2)
else:
    # Standard gradient pental
    gradient_penalty = tf.reduce_mean(tf.clip_by_value(slopes - 1., 0., np.infty)**2)
```

PyTorch:

```
if not lipschitz_penalty:
    # WGAN-GP Gradient Penalty for comparison
    penalty = ((slopes - 1) ** 2).mean()
else:
    # Lipschitz Penalty
    penalty = (torch.clamp(slopes - 1., min=0, max=None) ** 2).mean()
```